# Как вписать русскоязычные данные в код

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot

Хотелось бы в telegrambot добавить календарик с русскоязычными данными.Нашла интересный вариант(https://pypi.org/project/python-telegram-bot-calendar/), но не получается русскоязычные данные прописать. Подскажите, что я делаю не так?

```
your_translation_months = list('ЯнвФевМартМайИюньИюльАвгСентОктНояДек')
your_translation_days_of_week = list('ПнВтСрЧтвПтСубВс')

class MyTranslationCalendar(DetailedTelegramCalendar):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.days_of_week['yourtransl'] = your_translation_days_of_week
        self.months['yourtransl'] = your_translation_months

    ...

    @bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
    def start(m):
        calendar, step = DetailedTelegramCalendar().build()
        bot.send_message(m.chat.id,
                         f"Выберите {LSTEP[step]}",
                         reply_markup=calendar)

    @bot.callback_query_handler(func=DetailedTelegramCalendar.func())
    def cal(c):
        result, key, step = DetailedTelegramCalendar().process(c.data)
        if not result and key:
            bot.edit_message_text(f"Выберите {LSTEP[step]}",
                                  c.message.chat.id,
                                  c.message.message_id,
                                  reply_markup=key)
        elif result:
            bot.edit_message_text(f"Вы выбрали {result}",
                                  c.message.chat.id,
                                  c.message.message_id)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_tr = MyTranslationCalendar()
    bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

Comment: Во-первых вы смотрели, что в этих списках получается? Там просто все буквы из ваших строк. Во-вторых - вы никак это потом не применяете нигде.

Comment: @CrazyElf, благодарю за ответ. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в какую часть кода мне добавить эти списки?